# How to read from a static file using a Socket Text Stream with a Batch Interval of 10 seconds in Spark with Python?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have static file(log_file) with some 10K records in my local drive (windows). Structure is as follows.

```
"date","time","size","r_version","r_arch","r_os","package","version","country","ip_id"
"2012-10-01","00:30:13",35165,"2.15.1","i686","linux-gnu","quadprog","1.5-4","AU",1
```

I want to read this log records using a Socket Text Stream with a Batch Interval of 10 seconds and later I have to perform few spark operation either with RDD or DF computation. I have read below code just to read the data in time interval, split the same in the form of RDD and show.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Assignment4")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

data = ssc.socketTextStream("file:///SparkL2/log_file.txt",2222)
                            
linesrdd = data.map(lambda x: x.split(","))

linesrdd.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I saved this code and did a spark-submit from Anaconda command prompt. I am facing error in socketTextStream function, probably because I am not using it correctly.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\HP> cd c:\SparkL2
(base) PS C:\SparkL2> spark-submit Assignment5.py
20/09/09 21:42:42 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.net.UnknownHostException: file:///SparkL2/log_file.txt
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver.onStart(SocketInputDStream.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint.$anonfun$startReceiver$1(ReceiverTracker.scala:596)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint.$anonfun$startReceiver$1$adapted(ReceiverTracker.scala:586)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$submitJob$1(SparkContext.scala:2242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can any one help me on this. I am very new to pyspark and want to learn it by myself.

Comment: There are a couple of issues in the code: 1) Replace `.setMaster("local")` with `.setMaster("local[*]")` to use at least 2 CPU cores, 2) Use [Spark Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) instead. Can you edit your question and share the error?

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski I have added the error code. I think below line is incorrectly written. Do you have any clue to help me out.                                                                     data = ssc.socketTextStream("file:///SparkL2/log_file.txt",2222)